# Is it possible to create a full width background on a fixed-width div without a wrapper?

Tags: css

Is it possible to make div one look like div two without a wrapper? e.g. Extend the background image to fill 100% of the horizontal screen?

[Here is a fiddle demonstrating my question](https://jsfiddle.net/4hLswvtm/2/)

```css
div.one,
div.two {
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  color: #fff;
}
div.one,
div.wrapper {
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
  background-image: url("https://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/circles.png");
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  Div one is 300px wide and centered
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="two">
    Div two is 300px wide and centered with a 100%-width wrapper
    Is it possible to make div one look like div two without a wrapper?
  </div>
</div>
```

I was thinking `border-image` could be a solution, but not sure. I was also messing around with `clip-path: inset(0 -50rem 0 -50rem)`, but I can't seem to make the background-image show outside of the div's boundaries.

Comment: It's already full width, could you please elaborate what you expect ?
Any why not add background to the div second itself without fixed

Comment: I want div one to look like div two without the wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the background image on a pseudo element and position that and give it the dimensions of the body if it has no other closer ancestors which have position set.

Note, this snippet has set a narrower width for the element just so that it shows as narrower in the SO snippet system otherwise it looked OK in the snippet given in the question.

```css
div.one {
  width: 114px;
  margin: auto;
}
div.one::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
  background-image: url("https://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/circles.png");
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  Div one is 114px wide and centered
</div>
```

Comment: Pretty darn close and much appreciated. I added `clip-path: inset(0 -50rem 0 -50rem)` to `div.one` and it worked for that div. Problem is, any other divs on the page that are off-screen and require the same styling don't display properly. I made this fiddle as a demonstration: https://jsfiddle.net/9bjq4h1p/ I have a feeling this just isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
  width: 1140px;
  margin: auto;
}
   body {

  background-color: #1e1e1e;
  background-image: url("https://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/circles.png");
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  Div one is 1140px wide and centered
</div>
<div>
  <div class="two">
    Div two is 1140px wide and centered with a 100%-width wrapper
    Is it possible to create a full width background without a wrapper on a fixed-width div?
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you're right. I think using the `body` tag as the wrapper is the only way to do this reliably.